# Conectar un función con un botón PyQT5 Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy practicando con PyQT5 y creando una interfaz de prueba a través de Designer. Mi duda es como relaciono que al clickar un botón se ejecute una función.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 220, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # Ejecutar la función
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(mensaje)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


def mensaje():
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setText("Texto de prueba")
    msg.setDetailedText("Texto de prueba detallado")
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    msg.exec_()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El código es el generado con designer. He probado un código muy básico sin clases y me ejecuta la función pero aquí no.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: estás teniendo un gran problema en las importaciones, por lo que se ve ya te falta: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox sino agregar a cada llamada QtWidgets por ejemplo:  msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox() y así a cada instancia a este widget

Comment: Cierto... Efectivamente ese era el problema, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si has solucionado tu problema agrega una respuesta, de lo contrario no se ha solucionado nada

Comment: @Christian o sea, con un cometario alcanza para solucionarlo y ...¿no es así acá?¿amérita una respuesta por una línea?

Comment: @tincopasan lo siento, recién me levantaba y vi que el título decía `solucionado` así que procedí a dejar el comentario. Por otra parte, no tienes que ser tu el que haga la respuesta, puede ser el OP y en caso de ser algún error muy sencillo y que no aporta a la comunidad se borra la pregunta

Comment: @Christian no importa de quien sea la respuesta, sería una exageración por lo corta que puede ser, claro que siempre hay alguien que la complica como si fuese mecánica cuántica , con respecto a lo de simple y que no aporta a la comunidad es subjetivo, hay cada pregunta muy simple y con respuestas que no aportan nada para mí y sin embargo siguen ahí.

Comment: @tincopasan igual se puede dar respuestas cortas y simples, si la pregunta lo amerita. En cuanto a las preguntas que no aportan estas solo son eliminadas por los autores o moderadores, por lo que se entiende su existencia.